# Showing a combined tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say that I have a MySQL table that looks like this :

```
 BookTitle    Chapter    DateAdded  
  Book1          3       2012-12-15
  Book1          2       2012-12-16 
  Book1          1       2012-12-15
  Book2          2       2012-12-16
```

I want to show it in HTML so it can look like this :

```
 Book2      2
 Book1      2,3,1
```

Basically I want to get rid of the title of the book if existed! and group all the chapters together and sort them by the date

I was thinking of using `Group By` but all my experiments did not work. Please give me a solution or an advice. I am able to use PHP and MySQL I am currently using a Smarty template on this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can do this in `MySQL`. Use `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT BookTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(Chapter) ChapterList
FROM tableName
GROUP BY BookTitle
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb760/8)

Other Source

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: what if I wanted to put a limit on the "chapters results" so it can only show the two most recent chapters. I tried 

`GROUP_CONCAT(Chapter ORDER BY DateAdded DESC, Chapter DESC Limit 0,2)` but it is not working!

Comment: @shnisaka `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't accept a `LIMIT` parameter. From what I can tell, you'd have to use string manipulation functions (in MySQL query or in PHP) to get the text from the beginning of the string up to the second comma.

Comment: @user113215 is right shnisaka. Other way is to modify the query but you need to read some important points here: [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)